# Функции работы с ссылками на методы не работают для api < 24 в Retrolambda

Tags: android, lambda

Используя фреймворк Retrolambda (для поддержки некоторых свйств java8),

столкнулся с такой проблемой, некоторые функции касающиеся ссылок на методы работают только с api24 и больше. 
Например:

```
Function<Double, Double> Sqr = val -> val * val;
textView.setText("Square: " + Double.toString(Sqr.apply(2.0)) );
```

строку `Sqr.apply(2.0)` компилятор подчеркивает и говорит что нужно минимальное api24 (у меня минимальное стоит api15).

Другой пример:

```
    Consumer<Integer> fun1 = Person::increaseScore;
    fun1.accept(12);
```

Метод `accept(12);` подчеркивается и такая же ошибка.

Это я что-то неправильно настроил в Retrolambda или вышеприведенные вещи действительно можно выполнять только для андроид версии api24 и выше ?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Список того, что бэкпортит ретролямбда](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda#backported-language-features)

Тут ни слова про добавление новых методов в старые API.

> **Lambda expressions** are backported by converting them to anonymous
>   inner classes. This includes the optimization of using a singleton
>   instance for stateless lambda expressions to avoid repeated object
>   allocation.
>
> **Method references** are basically just syntax sugar for lambda
>   expressions and they are backported in the same way.
>
> **Try-with-resources statements** are backported by removing calls to
>   Throwable.addSuppressed if the target bytecode version is below Java
>   7. If you would like the suppressed exceptions to be logged instead of swallowed, please create a feature request and we'll make it
>   configurable.
>
> **Objects.requireNonNull calls** are replaced with calls to
>   Object.getClass if the target bytecode version is below Java 7. The
>   synthetic null checks generated by JDK 9 use Objects.requireNonNull,
>   whereas earlier JDK versions used Object.getClass.
>
> **Optionally also:**
>
> Default methods are backported by copying the default methods to a
>   companion class (interface name + "$") as static methods, replacing
>   the default methods in the interface with abstract methods, and by
>   adding the necessary method implementations to all classes which
>   implement that interface.
>
> Static methods on interfaces are backported by moving the static
>   methods to a companion class (interface name + "$"), and by changing
>   all methods calls to call the new method location.

И отдельным пунктом

> Known Limitations
>
> **Does not backport Java 8 APIs.**

Comment: Спасибо, получается по сути retrolyambda не поддерживает Consumer, apply и прочее.

Answer (score 3):

Убедитесь, что все классы, что вы используете, импортированы из `com.annimon.stream.function` а не из `java.util.function`, эти классы называются однаково и часто возникает путаница

`java.util.function` - принадлежать восьмой джаве, и не доступны до api24
`com.annimon.stream.function` - это, собсна, ретролямда.

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНО**

Если вы не хотите каждый раз сами следить за тем, что вы импортируете, то исключите из автоимпорта те классы, которые носят такие же названия, что и классы ретролямбды. Для этого идите в File->Settings->Editor->General-> Auto import. Там вы найдете раздел Exclude from import and Completion. Туда вы можете добавить, например, `java.util.function.Function`, чтобы вы никогда не спутали его с `com.annimon.stream.function.Function`

Comment: Спасибо, только `com.annimon.stream.function.Function` это уже другой фреймворк как я понял, а не retrolambda.

Comment: Да, тут возникла путаница, ретролямбда и аннимон это две разные вещи. Просто аннимон стримы не работают без ретролямбды, поэтому они иногда смешиваются в моей голове. Используйте https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API в связке с ретролябмдой и вы сможете использовать и Consumer и Function и прочие вкусности)

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, спасибо большое.